# More items to be filtered in my angular project

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm creating a test project and I put a filter where I can filter the last name from my list of users.
But I wanted to filter not only the last name but also the name, email and username.
I tried to think of how to make these changes in my code but I couldn't so far. I wanted to know if you could help me.

My HTML:

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lastname" (input)="Search()"/>
<mat-table [dataSource]="usuarios">
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nome </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.firstName }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- Last Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Sobrenome</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.lastName }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- UserName Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Username</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.username }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- Email Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>E-mail</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.email }}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container> ....
```

My component.ts:

```js
export class GerenciamentoUsuariosListaComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() usuarios: any[] = [];
  usuarios1: any;
  lastname :string;

 ..

  readonly displayedColumns = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'username','email','actions'];

  constructor(private service: GerenciamentoUsuariosService) {
    this.lastname = '';

  }


..

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshListUser1()
  }


  refreshListUser1() {
    this.usuarios1 = this.service.list().subscribe(
      resp => {
        this.usuarios = resp.content
       console.log(this.usuarios)

      });

  }


  Search(){
    if(this.lastname != ""){
      this.usuarios = this.usuarios.filter(res =>{
        return res.lastName.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.lastname.toLocaleLowerCase());
      })
    }else if(this.lastname == ""){
      this.ngOnInit();
    }

  }
}
```

If I missed more information and you need it, please let me know.

Comment: do you want full match or patial match?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out based on as many condition you want

```
this.usuarios = this.usuarios.filter(res =>{
    const keyword = this.lastname.toLocaleLowerCase();
    return res.firstName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(keyword) || 
           res.lastName.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(keyword) ||
           res.username.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(keyword) ||
           res.email.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(keyword);
    
});
```

That is for the partial search and if you want full search then you need to do the equality check.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you brother, I will try to do that test you passed.
This filter I created, would it also be able to filter users if they come by pagination? because the endpoint I'm using I'm going to bring paginated, since in the future there will be many users

Comment: that filter is using `usuarios` if you are using pagination and mapping that data to that variable then it will work.

Comment: that code above works! Thanks my friend!
Now, I am going to verify the question about pagination. I have the endpoint that is used to perform the filter directly within the database : /api/users?search=